# How to trace log details in the log file in ADempiere

Tags: log4j, erp, adempiere

I want to log the instances during the application run in the generated log files. For testing I have added the following code in beforeSave() of MOrder.

```
log.log(Level.SEVERE, " //SEVERE Log details)");
log.log(Level.WARNING, "//WARNING Log details)");
```

I have run the server and made a .jnlp client installation. While creating Sales Order the log details are displayed on the server but not traced in the generated log file.

In Preference : `Trace Level`  is `WARNING` and `Trace file` is `true`

In ADempiere server Management(Web view), The Trace Level is warning and I could trace the log details in file while I created the Sales Order using web window.

Is there anything I missed to trace the log details in application level?

Comment: ADempiere system is not tracing the log details, if we are using the jnlp client installation. you can find log file at server in jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/log

Answer (score 0):

ADempiere software structure are divided in 2 pieces.:

Client :

1. Desktop with jnlp
2. Swing_product.zip
3. Web interface (zkwebui)

Server:

1. Document processor
2. Accounting processor
3. Scheduler and workflow processor
4. DB Transactions and jboss app.

Everything happens on system still logged on server logs, %Adempiere_Home%/logs